# Add text into string between single quotes using regexp

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use Python to add some escape characters into a string when I print to the terminal.

```py
import re

string1 = "I am a test string"
string2 = "I have some 'quoted text' to display."
string3 = "I have 'some quotes' plus some more text and 'some other quotes'.

pattern = ... # I do not know what kind of pattern to use here
```

I then want to add the console color escape (`\033[92m` for green and `\033[0m` to end the escape sequence) and end characters at the beginning and end of the quoted string using something like this:

```py
result1 = re.sub(...)
result2 = re.sub(...)
result3 = re.sub(...)
```

with the end result looking like:

```py
result1 = "I am a test string"
result2 = "I have some '\033[92mquoted text\033[0m' to display."
result3 = "I have '\033[92msome quotes\033[0m' plus some more text and '\033[92msome other quotes\033[0m'.
```

What kind of pattern should I use to do this, and is `re.sub` an appropriate method for this, or is there a better regex function?

Comment: It's quite tricky to do "counted" replacements like this with a regex.  In my opinion, you should just scan the string character by character, so you can keep track of "open" vs "close".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to capture [negated `'`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) within single quotes.

```
res = re.sub(r"'([^']*)'", r"'\033[92m\1\033[0m'", s)
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/CrWwi8/2) or a [Python demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##VY7LCsIwEEXX5iuGbNKKlD5WLvwAv6FRiHSwBdPEzFTs19f0IejuzuWcy/iRW9dX09RZ7wJDQCEITpBI4tD19yJmLc9gLBhgJIa111L3Uuw2qtyo1rwQyFkE9RwcYxOVNytgB01H/mHG7F@sfkW1mItICvxjoHXLuoDLEJi@2SjHLYYvm8XJVIiA8@cBMxpuSZAqqa/qsk@VPEC8dF5V9bG0ulhSbueeoubjI5xEOZ2mDw) (`\1` [refers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) *first group*)

Comment: Taking the extra escape backslash out before the color code solved the problem: `res = re.sub(r"'([^']*)'", r"'\033[92m\1\033[0m'", s)`. That was causing it to print as a literal backslash instead of escaping in the console. Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: You're welcome @SandPiper! I see, have updated the answer accordingly.